# Change of folder specs in AMI 4+

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-ami

There is a similar question here - [Spark not installed on EMR cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619400/spark-not-installed-on-emr-cluster)

But what I am trying to know is - there was .versions folder on AWS EMR cluster before AMI 4 versions e.g. ".versions/2.4.0-amzn-7/etc/hadoop" also there were spark installation folders on /home/hadoop.

Now everything is on /etc/ folder - like /etc/hadoop/conf

Is there any particular reason behind this config. Basically I need to custom bootstrap and I used /home/hadoop previously so I now need to shift to /etc/ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation for emr-4.x releases, in particular this page that details these kind of differences from prior versions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-differences.html